# react-query: is there a proper way to enable query only on user action?

Tags: react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm new to react-query and we're trying to migrate some things from Redux.

Let's say I have a page where I can search for supports according to some filters. The thing is that I need the query to be done only when the user clicks on the search button and not automatically.

According to the react query documentation, to disable a query from running automatically you can use the enabled=false option to “permanently” disabling a query and then later trigger a refetch. It is also mentioned that Lazy Queries can be used to defer the initial query according to certain conditions…

The thing is that, in the example, it takes into account a filter where the first request is fired when the user enters a certain value for the filter:

```
function Todos() {
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState('')

  const { data } = useQuery({
      queryKey: ['todos', filter],
      queryFn: () => fetchTodos(filter),
      // ⬇️ disabled as long as the filter is empty
      enabled: !!filter
  })

  return (
      <div>
        //  applying the filter will enable and execute the query
        <FiltersForm onApply={setFilter} />
        {data && <TodosTable data={data}} />
      </div>
  )
}
```

But in my case all the filters are optional, that is, if the user does not enter any filter and presses the search button, the api returns all the supports.

This is the page where I have both the filter and table components (where the results from the api are shown)

```
const Supports = () => {
  const rowsPerPage = useAppSelector((state) => state.supports.rowsPerPage);
  const currentPage = useAppSelector((state) => state.supports.currentPage);
  const filters = useAppSelector((state) => state.supports.filters);
  const enableQuerySupports = useAppSelector((state) => state.supports.enableQuerySoportes);

  const { supports, total, isInitialLoading, isError, refetch } = useSupports(currentPage, rowsPerPage, filters, enableQuerySupports);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Grid item>
        <SupportsFilters />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <SupportsTable supports={supports} total={total} isLoading={isInitialLoading} isError={isError} />
      </Grid>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Supports;
```

It is worth mentioning that the results of the api are paginated and that you can also change the page size according to a query param (page and size respectively)

So in this case we decided (for now) to keep part of Redux to manage the current page, page size and filters for each module. Also because we need to maintain the page where the user had left in case of navigating to another module. (For example: if the user is in the SupportsA module and paging 10 times, then navigates to the SupportsB module and returns to the SupportsA module, the view should be left with the filters and supports loaded previously)

This is part of the ui for more reference:

[image: supports ui]

So in the filters component we have something like this in the handler for the form:

```
const SupportsFilters  = ({}: SupportsFiltersProps) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  ...
  
  const handleFormSubmit: SubmitHandler<SupportsFiltersWeb> = (data) => {
    dispatch(filtersSubmitted(data));
    if (currentPage !== 0) dispatch(currentPageUpdated(0));
    if (!enableQuerySoportes) dispatch(querySoportesEnabled(true));
  };

  return (
      ...
  );
};

export default SupportsFilters ;
```

As you can see we are enabling the query (regardless of the filters) with a state stored in Redux, then because this state is updated, the top component is rendered again and since it gets this state and uses the useSupports hook it finally gets the supports data. (once enabled, the query obtains more data in case the page, page size or filters are modified)

The hook looks something like this

```
export const useSupports = (currentPage: number, rowsPerPage: number, filters: Filters, enableQuerySoportes: boolean) => {
  const { data, isInitialLoading, isLoading, isError, error, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['supportsA', currentPage, rowsPerPage, formatFilters(filters)],
    queryFn: async () =>
      await client.obtainSupports(currentPage, rowsPerPage, formatFilters(filters)),
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    enabled: enableQuerySoportes,
  });

  return {
    supports: data?.data || [],
    isInitialLoading,
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error,
    total: data?.total || 0,
    refetch,
  };
};
```

Finally, in the SupportsTable component, pagination and page size are handled something like this:

```
const SupportsTable = ({ supports, isLoading, total, isError }: SupportsTableProps) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  ...

  const currentPage = useAppSelector((state) => state.RDDsoportes.currentPage);

  const handleChangePage = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement> | null, newPage: number) => {
    dispatch(currentPageUpdated(newPage));
  };
  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    if (currentPage !== 0) dispatch(currentPageUpdated(0));
    dispatch(rowsPerPageUpdated(+event.target.value));
  };

  ...

  if (isLoading) {
    return (...)
  }

  ...
};

export default SupportsTable;
```

where, again, when updating the current page or the page size, the top component is re-rendered and since the hook has these states as a dependency, it obtains the data if necessary.

My main concern is whether this solution is not a bit "far-fetched" to do something as simple as querying this data and displaying it (taking into account the pagination and page size).

Also mention that with the component structure shown above, when searching for supports, the components are rendered many times, which contributes (a little) to the question of whether this approach is correct.

Comment: There's no issues with your code, and it looks like you just need someone to review it. This question belongs in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/